# NodeJS and Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have inspected several answers and guides but couldn't make all parts working together.

Defined a very simple Node/Express project (test2)
main file is index.js

here is my project.js

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [ "es2017" ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "babel-node": "babel-node --presets=es2017",
    "start": "nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- ./dist/index.js",
    "build": "babel src -d dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.11.6",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.0",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  }
}
```

I have an es6 command in one of my files: console.log(Date.now().toDateString() + " : " + text.padStart(indent));

I performed npm start and it built dist library,
However it looks that under this library it didn't change the code and I can see padStart and toDateString as well. (with 'use strict' on top - so something did happens)

When I try running it I am getting:

```
> npm start

> test2@1.0.0 start D:\MyData\newJSTests\express\test2
> nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- ./dist/index.js

[nodemon] 1.14.11
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `npm run babel-node ./dist/index.js`

> test2@1.0.0 babel-node D:\MyData\newJSTests\express\test2
> babel-node --presets=es2017 "./dist/index.js"

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
...
```

I have tried placing in project.js:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon dist/index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2017,stage-2",
    "build": "babel lib -d dist",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
  },
```

But getting the same issue.
I am probably missing something. Will appreciate some help.
Thanks

Edit:
1. My mistake - regarding teh port, BUT,
2. It looks like the babel is not converting well.

```
D:\MyData\newJSTests\express\test2>npm start

> test2@1.0.0 start D:\MyData\newJSTests\express\test2
> nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- ./dist/index.js

[nodemon] 1.14.11
[nodemon] ...
[nodemon] starting `npm run babel-node ./dist/index.js`

> test2@1.0.0 babel-node D:\MyData\newJSTests\express\test2
> babel-node --presets=es2017 "./dist/index.js"

listening on port 3000!
TypeError: Date.now(...).toDateString is not a function
    at Object.myLogger (D.../dist/tools/logger.js:8:36)
```

Comment: read the error, Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000. You have already a process running on that port, probably the same on a different shell ?

Comment: 1. Thanks, 2. See my edit.